# How to add own c++ header file in electron？

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I'm new to electron and want to call c++ dll, that works fine.  I now want to know how to add my own header file in electron. I tried root dictionary and some other deeper place, but only got:

> `fatal error C1083: cannot open file: “MyDriver.h”: No such file or directory [c:\Users\75803\Documents\GitHub\native_addon\node_modules\hello\build\hello.vcxproj`

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Please show some sample code

Comment: I work it out.Just put your header file iojs-(yoour electron version)/src folder.Hope this will help people with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

OP worked this out by himself.

Solution is to put the custom header file in the folder

```
iojs-(yoour electron version)/src
```